# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str in command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm getting this error: `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str in command` on this command and I'm a little unsure where I'm going wrong here. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
@checks.can_embed()
@commands.command(name="botinfo")
async def botinfo(self, ctx: UKGCtx):
    """Shows advanced information about the bot."""
    char_count = 0
    deaths_count = 0
    levels_count = 0
    with closing(userDatabase.cursor()) as c:
        c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM chars")
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result is not None:
            char_count = result["count"]
        c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM char_deaths")
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result is not None:
            deaths_count = result["count"]
        c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM char_levelups")
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result is not None:
            levels_count = result["count"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fetchone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) returns a sequence (in this case a tuple) or `None`, not a dictionary.

If you would like it to return a dictionary, you can replace [`Connection.row_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) like this example from the documentation:

```
import sqlite3

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.row_factory = dict_factory
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select 1 as a")
print(cur.fetchone()["a"])
```